# How do you "empty" a StringWriter in Java?

Tags: java, io

What is the correct way to "empty" a [`StringWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) in Java so that I can reuse the `StringWriter` without having to create a new one?  Neither [`StringWriter.flush()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html#flush()) nor [`StringWriter.close()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html#close()) seem to have the desired effect.

Comment: In what way do they not have the desired effect?  Also, why do you want to reuse it instead of creating a new one?

Comment: They don't empty the `StringWriter` buffer, which is the effect that I desire.

Comment: Did you look the code source of StreamWriter flush ^^ ?    /**
     * Flush the stream.
     */
    public void flush() {
    }

Answer (score 66, accepted):

How about calling `getBuffer().setLength(0)`?

Comment: If you initially set the StringWriter to a specified size, will this setLength reduce that size to 0?

Comment: This keeps the capacity of the buffer the same. If you want to deallocate the  memory, use `writer.getBuffer().trimToSize();` after setting the length.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, we could also delete the buffer using the following code:

```
StringBuffer buf = ****.getBuffer();
buf.delete(0,buf.length());
```

Comment: Does this clear the buffer contents or deallocate the buffer storage?  In this case, I want to clear the contents.

Comment: If it deallocates the memory for the cleared Buffer, I am not sure... You could check with buf.capacity()

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#delete-int-int- is not clear, but seems to suggest that it does not change the buffer size.